# Creative approoach to understanding advanced math notation

Tags: self-learning

I was very pleased when I [saw Hilbert curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) and as a student I am interested to learn advanced mathematical concepts such as Hilbert spaces in an interesting and creative way.

In many [papers](https://arxiv.org/) I am finding terms like "Lipschitz domain", "sufficiently regular", "Borel sets" and similar terms, and I am having **hard time** to check or re-check the definitions from Wikipedia. It is even harder because definitions link to many new pages so it really takes time to get the right mindset to start understanding the **juice** out of the mathematical concepts.

For me creative approach is equivalent as putting your mind in some kind of isolation that you can break or bypass only if you have the right mindset. Imagine you are Hilbert now walking in the beautiful garden full of roses and you say gotcha! I just created the idea of Hilbert spaces, after being in  Euclidean spaces.

Is there any known approaches that provides this kind of learning experience for math.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks, I see but my wish to learn smart is not. :)

Comment: The Moore method, and later the inquiry-based learning movement, have been attempts to present learning math as a process of guided discovery. I wish there were a lot more books written in that style.

Comment: You say almost nothing about your background, but unless you're at an advanced graduate level (already passed qualifying exams), trying to pick up mathematics by reading research papers is simply wasting your time. Instead, look at papers in [Pi Mu Epsilon Journal](http://www.pme-math.org/journal/issues.html) and [Mathematical Spectrum](http://www.appliedprobability.org/content.aspx?Group=ms&Page=allmsissues) and [Quantum](https://www.nsta.org/quantum-magazine-math-and-science). And maybe the book [**Conjecture and Proof**](https://bookstore.ams.org/clrm-15) by Miklós Laczkovich.

Comment: There are various substances that provide the kind of experience you describe, but all of them are illegal and dangerous. I'd recommend getting a good textbook, instead.